# Vault dev mode initialization error as non-root user in alpine container: /dev/null/.vault not a directory

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, hashicorp-vault

The title kind of sums it up. The Dockerfile is below. I get no other errors in the build. The docker run command spits out the `Error initializing` shown below when I set the user to vault before the `ENTRYPOINT`.

- If I comment out `USER vault` the server starts without error.
- If I remove the -dev option to `vault server` but leave `USER vault` the server starts without error.

What's it looking for in /dev/null, or why is it looking there? I can't turn up any references to /dev/null in any related googling.

```
> docker build -t vault-deploy .
> docker run --rm -it --cap-add=IPC_LOCK -p 127.0.0.1:8200:8200 vault-deploy



         Api Address: http://0.0.0.0:8200
                 Cgo: enabled
     Cluster Address: https://0.0.0.0:8201
          Listener 1: tcp (addr: "0.0.0.0:8200", cluster address: "0.0.0.0:8201", max_request_duration: "1m30s", max_request_size: "33554432", tls: "disabled")
           Log Level: trace
               Mlock: supported: true, enabled: false
             Storage: file
             Version: Vault v0.11.0

Error initializing Dev mode: open /dev/null/.vault: not a directory
```

**vault-dev-config.hcl:**

```
storage "file" {
  path = "/var/vault/data"
  }
```

(I get the same behavior if I use `storage "inmem" {}` or just let it use the default config.)

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM [INTERNAL DOCKER IMAGE REPOSITORY]/alpine-python3

# Vault is in the testing repository, edge branch.
RUN echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
# Container packages.
# libcap: For the setcap executable.
# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
RUN apk update \
    && apk --no-cache add -u vault \
    && apk add --update libcap \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*


# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
# Execution configuration.
# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
# We won't run as root.
RUN mv /usr/sbin/vault /usr/bin
RUN chown vault /usr/bin/vault

# Make sure the vault executable can run mlock to prevent swapping to disk. We
# also have to run the container with --cap-add=IPC_LOCK.
RUN setcap cap_ipc_lock=+ep $(readlink -f /usr/bin/vault)

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
# Create and set ownership of /var/vault.
# Only needed if we're putting a file storage back end here.
# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
RUN mkdir /var/vault
RUN chown -R vault:vault /var/vault

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
# Create, populate and set ownership of /etc/vault.
# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
RUN mkdir /etc/vault

COPY vault-dev-config.hcl /etc/vault/vault-dev-config.hcl
RUN chmod 600 /etc/vault/vault-dev-config.hcl

RUN chown -R vault:vault /etc/vault

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
# Prepare for launch.
# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
USER vault
#Error initializing Dev mode: open /dev/null/.vault: not a directory

ENTRYPOINT vault server \
    -dev \
    -log-level trace \
    -dev-listen-address 0.0.0.0:8200 \
    -config /etc/vault/vault-dev-config.hcl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fond the answer on a Vault google group. In Dev mode Vault writes the root key to `$HOME/.vault`. In my container the vault user has no login or `$HOME`, so `$HOME` defaulted to `/dev/null`. Setting `$HOME` to `/var/vault` solved the problem.